# Pandas multiindex sum on one slice, set others to zero

Tags: pandas

I have a three-dim Series like this

```
start_date = '2020-01-01'
end_date = '2020-03-01'
date_range = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='MS')
axis_1, axis_2 = ['A','B'], ['red','blue']
iterables = [date_range, axis_1, axis_2 ]
index_names = ['time', 'level 1','level 2']
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=index_names)
df = pd.Series(_data, index=multi_index)
```

which looks like this:

```
level 0     level 1  level 2
2020-01-01  A        red        0.5
                     blue       0.5
            B        red        0.5
                     blue       0.5
2020-02-01  A        red        0.5
                     blue       0.5
            B        red        0.2
                     blue       0.2
2020-03-01  A        red        0.2
                     blue       0.2
            B        red        0.2
                     blue       0.2
dtype: float64
```

I want to sum up along level [0,1], in other words red+blue for each row. However, I want to assign the sum to `red` and set `blue` to zero.

Like this:

```
level 0     level 1  level 2
2020-01-01  A        red        1.0
                     blue       0.0
            B        red        1.0
                     blue       0.0
2020-02-01  A        red        1.0
                     blue       0.0
            B        red        0.4
                     blue       0.0
2020-03-01  A        red        0.4
                     blue       0.0
            B        red        0.4
                     blue       0.0
dtype: float64
```

Help is much appreciated.

In my actual DF, the number different values for all levels is large, so I don't want explicitly refer to these, except, of course, to the label 'red' that I want to assign to.

Comment: can you check your code I get an error `_data` is not defined.

Comment: `_data = [0.5]*6+[0.2]*6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try something like this:

```
df_sum = df.sum(level=[0,1]).to_frame()
df_sum['level 2'] = 'red'
df_sum.set_index('level 2', append=True).reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)[0]
```

Output:

```
time        level 1  level 2
2020-01-01  A        red        1.0
                     blue       0.0
            B        red        1.0
                     blue       0.0
2020-02-01  A        red        1.0
                     blue       0.0
            B        red        0.4
                     blue       0.0
2020-03-01  A        red        0.4
                     blue       0.0
            B        red        0.4
                     blue       0.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using `pandas` and `numpy` which is maybe a contra.

```
import numpy as np
sum_val = df.groupby(['time', 'level 1']).sum().values
new_val = np.dstack((sum_val, np.zeros(len(a)))).flatten()
pd.Series(new_val, index=multi_index)


time        level 1  level 2
2020-01-01  A        red        1.0
                     blue       0.0
            B        red        1.0
                     blue       0.0
2020-02-01  A        red        1.0
                     blue       0.0
            B        red        0.4
                     blue       0.0
2020-03-01  A        red        0.4
                     blue       0.0
            B        red        0.4
                     blue       0.0
dtype: float64
```